# Dúvida sobre manipulação de data utilizando time.h

Tags: c, data

estou estudando C e pensando sobre um problema me deparei com a necessidade de estudar a biblioteca time.h.

Basicamente, gostaria de calcular a diferença entre duas datas sem precisar reinventar a roda. Para isso considerei 2 datas hipotéticas:

04/12/2018 12:00

04/12/2018 13:00

Espero que a diferença entre essas duas datas seja 1 hora (3600 segundos).

Para isso, estou utilizando a seguinte rotina:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    time_t seconds, sec1, sec2;

    struct tm *dataTimeBegin = (struct tm *)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
    struct tm *dataTimeEnd = (struct tm *)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));

    dataTimeBegin->tm_mday = 4;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_mon = 11;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_year = 2018 - 1900;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_hour = 12;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_min = 00;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_sec = 00;

    dataTimeEnd->tm_mday = 4;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_mon = 11;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_year = 2018 - 1900;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_hour = 13;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_min = 00;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_sec = 00;

    sec1 = mktime(dataTimeBegin);
    sec2 = mktime(dataTimeEnd);

    printf("sec1: %ld\n", sec1);
    printf("sec2: %ld\n", sec2);

    printf("difftime(sec2, sec1): %f", difftime(sec2, sec1));

    return 0;
}
```

Contuno, verifiquei um comportamento estranho. A minha saída indica:

sec1: 1543935600

sec2: 1543935600

difftime(sec2, sec1): 0.000000

Por que sec2 está igual sec1? Quando eu faço:

```
    dataTimeBegin->tm_mday = 4;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_mon = 11;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_year = 2018 - 1900;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_hour = 13;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_min = 00;
    dataTimeBegin->tm_sec = 00;

    dataTimeEnd->tm_mday = 4;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_mon = 11;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_year = 2018 - 1900;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_hour = 13;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_min = 00;
    dataTimeEnd->tm_sec = 00;
```

A minha saída fica:

sec1: 1543939200

sec2: 1543935600

difftime(sec2, sec1): -3600.000000

Esse comportamento não faz sentido para mim. Estou vacilando em algum conceito?

EDIT:
Cheguei em casa e vim testar, vou adicionar duas imagens (eu cheguei a modificar o código para não usar ponteiro para struct tm) e agora quando uso o ponteiro está resultando correto e quando uso a struct direto dá errado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EDIT 2: Segui a recomendação do zentrunix e inicializei tm_isdst e deu certo nas duas versões (com o uso do ponteiro ou sem)

Comment: 1. por que você você está usando declarando as estruturas tm como ponteiros ? não precisa. 2. fiz o teste aqui com seu exemplo e funcionou dreitinho, como esperado..,a impressão que fica é que você inverteu os testes...

Comment: Eu usei ponteiros para tm porque na aplicação que estou pensando será necessário. Aqui está só uma parte inicial que comecei a testar. Acabei de testar o mesmo códio em ambiente linux e deu certo. Quando estou no vs code + mingW resulta exatamente na saída que postei. Vim para uma VM linux, executei e deu certo. tem alguma peculiaridade que não estou me atentando? Será que era algum cache?

Comment: Mas está a compilar como ? Com o gcc ? Qual o comando exato que usa ? Tendo em conta que indica comportamentos diferentes em sistemas diferentes, torna-se importante saber exatamente como está a compilar.

Comment: Ei @Isac, vou verificar. Mas o meu visual studio code está em um ambiente windows com o MinGW instalado. No ambiente linux eu executei "gcc teste.c -o teste". Em relação a compilação no ambiente windows, vou verificar assim que chegar em casa, mas acredito que é a mesma coisa, porém com o .exe "gcc teste.c -o teste.exe".

Comment: Inicialize o flag de horário de verão (daylight saving time), é possível que seja isso. (campo tm_isdst da estrutura tm).

Comment: Caro @zentrunix, editei minha pergunta mostrando o print. Ocorre que usando ponteiro funcionou (ontem não estava funcionando) e usando a struct direto não funcionou (sec1 e sec2 retornaram iguais). Fiz o que vc comentou, inicializei tm_isdst e agora deu certo nos 2 casos. Obrigado.

Comment: Não coloque a solução na pergunta, que não é dessa forma que o site funciona. Crie uma resposta à pergunta explicando o que fez para resolver o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Tente alocar as estruturas tm usando calloc, ou limpe as mesmas completamente usando bzero, a estrutura tem outros campos além do que você preencheu e alguma sujeira neles pode estar influenciando o resultado.